# Can not add plugin to extbase extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

I added a third plugin to my extension with the key `Pi3`.

In my `ext_localconf.php` I configured the new plugin:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
'Vendx.' . $_EXTKEY,
'Pi3',
array(
    'New' => 'listnew',

),
// non-cacheable actions
array(
'New' => 'listnew',
)
);
```

In my `ext_tables.php` I registered it:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
$_EXTKEY,
'Pi3',
'New Items'
);
```

I created `Classes/Controller/NewController.php` with a `listnewAction()` and I also created `Resources/Private/Templates/Listnew.html`

When I install the extension and try to add a new plugin to a site I can not view the option in the plugin-dropdown as it gets stuck. It won't even open and the whole backend gets stuck. So I guess it must be something with the plugin configuration/registration.

**Why does this happen? What am I missing??**

P.S. when I remove that plugin, the extension works like normally and I am able to use the dropdown to select one of the other 2 plugins.

Comment: i just tested it on another system and seems the problem was with my dev-instance. No idea thoug what went wrong. Gonna dig into this and post any usefull information.

Answer (score 0):

Just suggestion: do not use reserved words like 'new' for action or controllers names it can cause unexpected errors.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I ve adapted it but still nothing.